Understanding Bitmask Immediates in ARM64 Assembly
I'm currently learning ARM64 assembly and I'm having trouble understanding how bitmask immediates are implemented and validated. I've read that ARM64 has specific rules for what constitutes a valid bitmask immediate, but I'm finding it difficult to grasp these rules in practice.
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/a/A64-General-Instructions/AND--immediate-?lang=en

Is the bitmask immediate. Such an immediate is a 32-bit or 64-bit pattern viewed as a vector of identical elements of size e = 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits. Each element contains the same sub-pattern: a single run of 1 to e-1 non-zero bits, rotated by 0 to e-1 bits. This mechanism can generate 5,334 unique 64-bit patterns (as 2,667 pairs of pattern and their bitwise inverse). Because the all-zeros and all-ones values cannot be described in this way, the assembler generates an error message.

For instance, I understand that 0x00FF00FF is valid:
AND x0, x1, #0x00FF00FF  // Valid

For example, I tried using the following instruction:
AND x0, x1, #0xF0F0

However, I get the following error:
<source>:15: Error: immediate out of range at operand 3 -- `and x0,x1,#0xF0F0'

What are the exact rules for a valid bitmask immediate in ARM64?
Why is 0xF0F0 considered an invalid bitmask immediate?
How can I determine if a given bitmask is valid or not?


0xf0f0 is a 16 bit pattern, not a 32 or 64 bit pattern.  Only the latter two are supported.  You could e.g. use 0xf0f0f0f0.

So how do I apply the right bitmask?
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/a/A64-General-Instructions/AND--immediate-?lang=en#:~:text=0%20to%2031.-,imm,-Is%20the%20bitmask
I could not understand the rules mentioned here. I have been trying to understand for 2 days but it is really very complicated. If you know, please explain. @fuz

To apply the right bitmask, you load the value 0xF0F0 into a register, and then use the version of AND that takes three register parameters, rather than two registers and an encoded immediate value.  AND immediate is a shortcut that can only be used in very specific cases (5334 out of the 18446744073709551616 possible 64-bit values), and 0xF0F0 isn't one of those cases.

@user25689009 Perhaps this article might be helpful.

If you're not sure the most efficient way to do something, ask a C compiler: return x & 0xF0F0;.  If the compiler knows any cool tricks for your specific case, it will use them.  In this case it has to just materialize the mask constant in another register with a separate instruction, unlike for a mask with all set bits contiguous, or where the pattern repeats out to the full width of the operand.  https://godbolt.org/z/cxo9dP5Kb

0xf0f0 is actually 0x0000f0f0, do you see a pattern of repeating identical bits? There isn't one in this case, pretty simple, no?

@rustyx: The operands are 64-bit registers (x0 not w0), so the value to be encoded is actually 0x000000000000f0f0.  But yes, that also doesn't have a power-of-2-sized pattern that repeats across the whole number

I don't think your first example AND x0, x1, #0x00FF00FF is actually valid.  The GNU assembler rejects it.  However, it happens to be equivalent to AND w0, w1, #0x00FF00FF which is valid; possibly you are using an assembler which is smart and replaces it for you?

The issue is that for a 64-bit instruction, the repeating pattern (here 0x00FF) has to fill all 64 bits.  So 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF would be valid, but 0x0000000000FF00FF is not.  But 0x00FF00FF is valid as a 32-bit immediate, and since instructions with a 32-bit destination register automatically zero-extend, the result is the same (low half of x0 contains the correct result, high half is zero which is also correct).

Instead of trying to think of it as "which values are valid", it might be helpful to think instead about how the instruction is decoded.  Encoded into the instruction are two numbers, s and r, as well as (in a tricky indirect fashion) a power-of-two e.  The decoder constructs an e-bit value whose s lowest bits are all 1 and the rest are 0 (i.e. the value (1 << s) - 1), rotates it right by r bits, and then replicates it to fill up 32 or 64 bits as appropriate.  It then uses this value in the requested bitwise logical operation.

So when you specify a value in your assembly source, the assembler works backwards to try to find values for s, r and e that would produce the value you requested.  If there is no combination of values that works, it reports an "immediate out of range" error.
